# How to fetch a thumbnail image from an url?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have an requirement for my application where user can paste a link from a site and it has to show a thumbnail of it. Like whatsapp does. [image]

Comment: You can fetch the page, and then extract data you need from it? Please add your efforts so far using a [mcve]. Also re-read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I really dont have any idea of how to do this. so  haven't written any code. I'll be glad if someone guides me.

Comment: SO isn't really meant for tutorials, but for questions about specific issues. -- Consider searching using keyword "scrape page using fetch javascript"